# ¿Cómo puedo salir del proceso de "Speaker" en Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente código en Node.JS:

```
var wav = require('wav');
var Speaker = require('speaker');
var reader = new wav.Reader();

fs.writeFile('output.wav', response, 'binary', err => {
          var file  = fs.createReadStream('output.wav');
          file.pipe(reader);
          reader.on('format', function (format) {
            var s= new Speaker(format);
            reader.pipe(s);
          });
        });
```

El problema es que al momento de ejecutarlo, una vez que termina de hablar el Speaker, me aparece este problema: `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..`. Estoy usando `Nodemon` para trabajar mi app.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto? Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Isaac. Podrias poner la traza completa del error? La linea que mencionas es del `nodemon` únicamente, la razón está en la traza. Si no te aparece la traza pudiera ser que no se esté capturando el error.

Comment: Hola @Angel , esto es lo que me regresa: `[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Running on port 1000
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: Parece que no estás capturando el error. `nodemon` está teniendo un error fatal y no le permite reiniciar hasta que detecte un cambio en tus ficheros. Te recomiendo que hagas un debug sencillo con `console.log()` para detectar en qué punto se quiebra la app.